# Vagrant UP / PuPHPet / VirtualBox - Can't build box

Tags: php, ruby, vagrant, activesupport, puphpet

I'm starting work on a Laravel project and I'm trying to initiate it with `vagrant up`. Three specific errors that are preventing me from creating the box.

1: not sure if this one is super critical but it was bright red on output.

```
==> default: gpg: 
==> default: directory `/root/.gnupg' created
==> default: gpg: 
==> default: new configuration file `/root/.gnupg/gpg.conf' created
==> default: gpg: 
==> default: WARNING: options in `/root/.gnupg/gpg.conf' are not yet active during this run
==> default: gpg: 
==> default: keyring `/root/.gnupg/secring.gpg' created
==> default: gpg: 
==> default: keyring `/root/.gnupg/pubring.gpg' created
==> default: gpg: 
==> default: requesting key D39DC0E3 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
==> default: gpg: 
==> default: /root/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
==> default: gpg: 
==> default: key D39DC0E3: public key "Michal Papis (RVM signing) <mpapis@gmail.com>" imported
==> default: gpg: 
==> default: no ultimately trusted keys found
==> default: gpg: 
==> default: Total number processed: 1
==> default: gpg: 
==> default:               imported: 1
==> default:   (RSA: 1)
```

2. The fact that activesupport won't install seems to be the cause of the 3rd error.

   `==> default: ERROR:  Error installing activesupport:
   ==> default:    activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.`
3. This error seemingly is a result of the 2nd error.

`==> default: Error: Could not autoload puppet/parser/functions/merge_yaml: cannot load such file -- active_support
==> default: Error: Could not autoload puppet/parser/functions/merge_yaml: cannot load such file -- active_support on node dev.<client>.com
==> default: Error: Could not autoload puppet/parser/functions/merge_yaml: cannot load such file -- active_support on node dev.<client>.com
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.`

I've tried changing the version of Ruby installed up to 2.2.6 and that caused even more errors. If you need my config or full `vagrant up` command then please let me know. Any help super appreciated.